# Why does this show up — minerd: command not found?

Tags: command-line, cpu

Trying to mine crypto, but just as I'm about to initiate the mining, it's unable to recognize the 'minerd' command?

Comment: How exactly did you install the software? Please [edit] and clarify.

Answer (score 1):

That error means exactly what it sounds like. There's no `minerd` command installed on the path. The most likely reason —if you've compiled it— is it's not installed on the global path.

And that's fine, you just need to tell it to run the local binary. In the POSIX world, this needs to be explicit. `cd` into the directory* where the binary is and run `./minerd`

<sub>*Accurate EnoughⓇ for this answer. You can also use the full path without changing directory.</sub>